# How to get the probability function $P(X)$ from $ P(X^2)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

[image: Q3]

**i have to know the 3 remaining value of $P(x)$**

I solved the question but I don’t know if it’s mathematically right .

I used the fact that :
$ E[X^2] = \sum x^2 P(X=x) $

But also

$ E[X^2] = \sum x^2P(X^2 = x^2) $

This is the first equation

The second comes from $Var(x^2)$ the same way I used

The third is that the sum of probability is $1$.

Can someone confirm ?

Comment: Please use MathJax instead of pasting images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to give your answer for us to confirm if it is correct.

Here is an easier way to get 3 equations to complete the probability function for $X$:

$P(X^2 = 9) = P(X = 3 \ \text{OR} \ X = -3) = P(X = 3)+P(X = -3)$

$P(X^2 = 4) = P(X = 2 \ \text{OR} \ X = -2) = P(X = 2)+P(X = -2)$

$P(X^2 = 0) = P(X = 0)$

Answer (score 0):

I cant add comment repuatation $+50$ so i got that  @JimmyK4542 :

$ P(x=0) = \frac{1}{4}$

$ P(x=2) = \frac{1}{8}$

$ P(x=3) = \frac{1}{4}$

I said that $ E[X^2] = E[X^2] $ but in two different ways the first uses $P(X)$ the second uses $P(X^2)$

$ E[X^2] = E[X^2] $ Gives:

$5.5 = \frac{9}{4} + \frac{4}{8} + 4P(X=2) + 9P(X+3)$

$ Var[X^2] = Var[X^2]  $ Gives:

$  \frac{57}{4} = \frac{121}{4}(\frac{5}{8} - P(X=2) - P(X=3)) + \frac{9}{4}P(X=2) + \frac{49}{4}P(X=3) $

Comment: You can edit this in your original post itself.

Comment: Are you assuming the distribution is symmetric?

Comment: sorry i will , but is it correct ? because i get the same  result as Jimmy . i liked his way to much simple but i want to know if this alright as well

Comment: Strictly speaking when you move from the space in $X$ to space in $X^2$. You are losing information. To gain that information back you will need extra condition.

Comment: @Mann so my result is alright by LUCK using it in any probabilty function will be wrong right ?? i simply replaced $X$ with $X^2$ in $E[X] = \sum xP(X=x)$ so i get $E[X^2]=\sum x^2P(X^2 = x^2)$ and $E[X^2] = \sum x^2P(X=x)$ is known before

Comment: @Razi refer to this answer. It's a bit advanced but it will set everything straight If you can understand it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3205671/random-variable-as-a-transformation-of-probability-space